# M2/ How to fix "Incompatible argument type: Required type: string. Actual type ..."

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, construct

A compilation was started.

> Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---] 
>   85% 1 min 404.0 MiB Errors during compilation:
>     SkyFox\Supplier\UI\DataProvider\Supplier\DataProvider
>
> **Incompatible argument type: Required type: string.**
>
> Actual type:\SkyFox\Supplier\UI\DataProvider\Supplier\name;
>
> File: /var/www/html/sky.local/app/code/SkyFox/Supplier/UI/DataProvider/Supplier/DataProvider.php
>
> Total Errors Count: 1
>                                             [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]
>   Error during compilation
>
> setup:di:compile

**This's my code:**

```
namespace SkyFox\Supplier\Model\Company;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider {

    /**
     * @var \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param $name
     * @param $primaryFieldName
     * @param $requestFieldName
     * @param \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->connection = $connection;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        foreach ($items as $supplier) {
            $this->loadedData[$supplier->getData('company_id')] = $supplier->getData();
        }

        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('supplier');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $supplier = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $supplier->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$supplier->getData('company_id')] = $supplier->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('supplier');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**Thanks all**

Comment: I don't understand, what's change in new code, how is this error? I get the same error. Can you help me fix it. Thanks. Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---] 85% 3 mins 380.0 MiBErrors during compilation: Sample\Subscribe\Ui\DataProvider\SubscribeToPrice\SubscribeToPriceDataProvider Incompatible argument type: Required type: string. Actual type: \Sample\Subscribe\Model\ResourceModel\SubscribeToPrice\CollectionFactory; File:C:/wamp64/www/Projects/app/code/Sample/Subscribe/Ui/DataProvider/SubscribeToPrice/SubscribeToPriceDataProvider.php Sample\Subscribe\Ui\DataProv

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140774)

Answer (score 36):

The error ***`Incompatible argument type: Required type: string. Actual type: \SkyFox\Supplier\UI\DataProvider\Supplier\name; File`*** is triggered because of the missing type in the `__construct` phpDoc annotation.

So the `__construct` phpDoc annotation need to be as below:

```
/**
 * DataProvider constructor.
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
 public function __construct(
     $name,
     $primaryFieldName,
     $requestFieldName,
     \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
     DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
     array $meta = [],
     array $data = []
) {
     $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
     $this->connection = $connection;
     parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
   }
```

Means:

**@param $name**

**@param $primaryFieldName**

**@param $requestFieldName**

Should be

**@param string $name**

**@param string $primaryFieldName**

**@param string $requestFieldName**

For more details check **`Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider`** class

You can also remove `\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,`
As you are not using it any where on the class.

Comment: This answer is gold.

Comment: So now even comments throw errors. #progress. *facepalm*

Comment: Faced a similar issue and updating the phpDoc worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
namespace SkyFox\Supplier\Model\Company;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider {

    /**
     * @var \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface
     */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        \SkyFox\Supplier\Model\ResourceModel\Supplier\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->connection = $connection;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();

        foreach ($items as $supplier) {
            $this->loadedData[$supplier->getData('company_id')] = $supplier->getData();
        }

        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('supplier');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $supplier = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $supplier->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$supplier->getData('company_id')] = $supplier->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('supplier');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, the error is triggered because of the missing type in the ```__construct``` phpDoc annotation. ```@param $name``` should be ```@param string $name```

Comment: Facing same issue. Any idea on this.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365278/magento-2-facing-error-to-override-dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

other workaround

```
public function __construct(
                            string $name,
                            string $primaryFieldName,
```