# Magento 2.3.1 Incompatible argument type

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, magento2.3.1, data-provider

I have an issue on compile on customs extension:

> ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Ui\DataProvider\Sales\Order\Donation\DataProvider
>         Incompatible argument type: Required type: string. Actual type:
>   \ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Ui\DataProvider\Sales\Order\Donation\name;
>   File: 
>   /var/www/html/app/code/ImaginationMedia/SocialOrder/Ui/DataProvider/Sales/Order/Donation/DataProvider.php
>
> Total Errors Count: 1
>
> In Log.php line 92:
>                                  Error during compilation

```
<?php

namespace ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Ui\DataProvider\Sales\Order\Donation;

use ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Model\Helper;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var Helper
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @var AddFieldToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFieldStrategies;

    /**
     * @var AddFilterToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFilterStrategies;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param $name
     * @param $primaryFieldName
     * @param $requestFieldName
     * @param Helper $helper
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $addFieldStrategies
     * @param array $addFilterStrategies
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Helper $helper,
        Session $session,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->addFieldStrategies = $addFieldStrategies;
        $this->addFilterStrategies = $addFilterStrategies;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->productId = $session->getCurrentDonationProduct();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->helper->getDonationOrders($this->productId);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $items = $this->getCollection();

        $items = $this->helper->getItemsInArray($items);

        $result = [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Add field to select
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $alias
     * @return void
     */
    public function addField($field, $alias = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFieldStrategies[$field])) {
            $this->addFieldStrategies[$field]->addField($this->getCollection(), $field, $alias);
        } else {
            parent::addField($field, $alias);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function addFilter(Filter $filter)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
                ->addFilter(
                    $this->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
                );
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try `* @param string $field
* @param string $alias` , just remove array and null

Comment: removed null and array & added both @param , same result as previous

Comment: can you post your whole code DataProvider.php

Comment: updated ,check out code above

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238349/m2-how-to-fix-incompatible-argument-type-required-type-string-actual-type

Comment: did it work now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> /**
>      * DataProvider constructor.
>      * @param $name                          <
>      * @param $primaryFieldName              <
>      * @param $requestFieldName              <
>      * @param Helper $helper
>      * @param Session $session
>      * @param array $addFieldStrategies
>      * @param array $addFilterStrategies
>      * @param array $meta
>      * @param array $data
>      */
```

I solved my issue by adding 'string'

```
      * DataProvider constructor.
      * @param string $name
      * @param string $primaryFieldName
      * @param string $requestFieldName
```

and then clearing Magento's root directory /var/cache and de-compile works

Comment: thats the same with my answer that i deleted haha anyway it s nice to know it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

namespace ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Ui\DataProvider\Sales\Order\Donation;

use ImaginationMedia\SocialOrder\Model\Helper;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var Helper
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $addFieldStrategies;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $addFilterStrategies;

    /**
     * @var $productId
     */
    private $productId;

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param string|null $name
     * @param $primaryFieldName
     * @param $requestFieldName
     * @param Helper $helper
     * @param Session $session
     * @param array $addFieldStrategies
     * @param array $addFilterStrategies
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Helper $helper,
        Session $session,
        array $addFieldStrategies = [],
        array $addFilterStrategies = [],
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->addFieldStrategies = $addFieldStrategies;
        $this->addFilterStrategies = $addFilterStrategies;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->productId = $session->getCurrentDonationProduct();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->helper->getDonationOrders($this->productId);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $items = $this->getCollection();

        $items = $this->helper->getItemsInArray($items);

        $result = [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $field
     * @param null $alias
     */
    public function addField($field, $alias = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFieldStrategies[$field])) {
            $this->addFieldStrategies[$field]->addField($this->getCollection(), $field, $alias);
        } else {
            parent::addField($field, $alias);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Filter $filter
     */
    public function addFilter(Filter $filter)
    {
        if (isset($this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()])) {
            $this->addFilterStrategies[$filter->getField()]
                ->addFilter(
                    $this->getCollection(),
                    $filter->getField(),
                    [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
                );
        } else {
            parent::addFilter($filter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above, cp original as bak.copy whole code and used this and run di compile. Same error

Comment: try updated answer @EdTan

Comment: what part has changed?

Comment: sorry I should have commented it here, I just just set the comment for name to be string and null

Comment: ahh the only difference is I put null on it but i think it should work as well

Comment: I see ,but I m not sure why this doesn't work for my compile .anyway i appreciate the help for pinpointing issue for me

Comment: yeah. it s okay. no problem ed